Read environment variables in Ktor Server
I have a server using Ktor and Koin that runs perfectly in dev environment (Intellij IDEA). The server is using ActiveMQ to communicate with the client. For that, I have an application-local.yaml file (with the io.ktor:ktor-server-config-yaml-jvm dependency) and have -config=application.yaml -config=application-local.yaml in the run config.
Now, here's my problem: I want to overload some YAML defined variables with environment variables when publishing the server to production (e.g the activemq borker uri). I am using Docker if this is any help, which means that the env variable will most likely be set in a docker-compose.yml file.
I am aware that the following syntax exists: "$ENV_VAR:default_value". But the problem is that the application-local.yaml file won't be in the production version of the application.
I am also aware that libraries exists to create a Ktor EnvConfig. But my main goal was to avoid using libraries outside of the main dependecies (such as Ktor, Kotlin, etc ...)
The expected behavior:
private const val activemqBrokerUriProperty = "com.company.module.activemq-url"

development environment (Intellij IDEA)
com:
  company:
    module:
      activemq-url: "failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?maxReconnectDelay=30000"

// activemqBrokerUriProperty defined in the application-local.yaml
// Will be equal to "failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?maxReconnectDelay=30000"
val activemqBrokerUri = environment.config.propertyOrNull(activemqBrokerUriProperty)?.getString()

production environment (Docker Deployment)
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e com.company.module.activemq-url="failover://(tcp://activemq:61616)maxReconnectDelay=30000" image-url:latest

// activemqBrokerUriProperty defined in the docker-compose.yml or directly in docker run command
// Will be equal to "failover:(tcp://activemq:61616)?maxReconnectDelay=30000"
val activemqBrokerUri = environment.config.propertyOrNull(activemqBrokerUriProperty)?.getString()

Right know, when I do the above line, I get the correct defined url in IDE (dev mode), but get null in docker image (prod mode). I was expecting it to blow up in docker since I'm not telling Ktor to use the application-local here. But I thought that defining a variable with the same name as env variable would suffice ?
I know I could just define the variable as a permanent env variable and do System.env(activemqBrokerUriProperty). But for architectural reasons, I need to get the above situation to work.

You've shown the expected behavior, but what is the actual behavior? Can you share the Docker and Docker Compose files?

@Uberhumus I added the behavior I currently have + the configs (yaml file and docker run command). The docker image is Gradle generated and no docker-compose is currently using this image. But some might use it if I get this to work.

Here's my theory, that I can't be sure of without seeing the Dockerfile. I suspect that the ENV declaration works for bash but isn't exported to the subprocess running the command. It's either that, or it could be a special character situation.

The simplest way you can solve this problem is to define a function that will return a property value defined in the config or a value of the corresponding environment variable. This function can be called instead of the propertyOrNull method to support the behavior you need.
